# getDisplayMedia Screenshot in Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, safari

This is the code to generate image,

```
console.log('--imageCapture');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  screenshot()
})

function screenshot(){
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

// Request media
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia().then(stream => 
{
  console.log(stream);
  
  let track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  
  let capture = new ImageCapture(track);
  
  capture.grabFrame().then(bitmap => 
  {
    // Stop sharing
    track.stop();
      
    // Draw the bitmap to canvas
    canvas.width = bitmap.width;
    canvas.height = bitmap.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
      
    const frame = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  });
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e)});
}
```

these code runs
It runs perfectly in Chrome, but it can't running in safari, is there any way to generate image in safari?

Comment: I did this recently but without the ImageCapture, just by assigning the stream to a video element and then drawing the video element into a canvas.

Comment: @somethinghere is that working in Safari? can you show me some code

Comment: @huhao Hello have you found a solution that work on Safari iOS?